# Related technologies question: on topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have come up with a new business idea (new for us at least) within our recruitment firm.

**Target audience:** People with software development skills who are speciliased in languages that are becoming redundant, especially developers 40 years and older

**The idea:** Retraining them to use a more current technology (shortlist for now is Angular, AWS, Docker) and offering a package of education, work experience and employment.

As we see it this solves two problems:

1. The huge shortage in qualified developers in these technologies
2. The difficulties people over 40 experience have in staying employed in the software industry.

We obviously need to make sure we recruit people who have skills in programming in "similar" languages to the ones we want to retrain them to use. Therefore I'm looking for the right place to ask which language specific experience would make prospective candidates likely to be able to adapt quickly to their new specialisation.

I'm not sure this question would be on topic as it does not concern programming itself, but I could not find a different Stack Exchange site that seems a likely source for conclusive answers on this.

Any advice on how to seek answers on this and where to post the question is more than welcome.

Comment: where is this fact that developers of 40 years old and older are becoming redundant, and with that level of experience they would be easily train themselves to use more current technologies.

Comment: No, such a question would come out either _primarily opinion based_, or _too broad_.

Comment: ciaran82: The training itself is not the issue. What many seem to struggle with is to obtain sufficient pratical experience in a new language to reach "employable" status.

Comment: I have never been so insulted. How dare you!

Comment: @RichardtenBrink I think you should rephrase your target audience to people that struggle to learn current technologies and not have an age specified on it, I am in college and my friend who is 21 struggles to learn technologies but the smartest person in the class is 38, it depends on the person not the age

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tone of many Stack Overflow posts are geared more towards concrete programming, and not much else. Other questions have to do with comprehension of design or code. Ethics and experiences are not often considered on-topic in my experience.

If you're going to try get opinions, perhaps you should try one of the chat rooms or Reddit. I don't think there's a definite, concrete answer that can be answered by one expert for how to transition from language to language--the answer's often subjective.

Comment: The opinions part is indeed why I hesitate to ask here. I could perhaps word the question in such a way that I ask only about similarities in code structure and such. Would that help?

Comment: @RichardtenBrink Only if it's based entirely on language features, but that won't get you nowhere because most of programming is in design and paradigms--syntax is not very important unless it molds how you program with the langauge, and "how it molds programming methodology" isn't exactly an objective topic either. I don't think we have "programming paradigm theory" as a concrete field of programming-psychology or what-not.